# scala refactor 2 almost identical case classes

Tags: scala, refactoring

I have the following case classes in scala:

```
case class Brand(brand: String, country: String)

object Brand {
  def func(data: (String, String)): Brand = {}
}


case class Manufacturer(manufacturer: String, country: String)

object Manufacturer {
  def func(data: (String, String)): Manufacturer = {}
}
```

As you can see, the problem here is that `Brand` and `Manufacturer` actually have the same structure, but they share different field names. So the same functions will need to be implemented twice, just with different output type. The logic is the same.

Is there a good way to refactor this code?

I prefer not to combine them into one case class such as

```
case class Attribute(attribute: String, country: String)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Share with us the "same logic" applied in both functions `func`. Is it a mapping `Tuple => case-class` that you're looking for ?

Comment: @GaëlJ yes it converts a tuple to case class

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Brand.tupled` instead of `Brand.func`, this removes the need for this function.

`tupled` is a method generated for case classes which takes a tuple as input and create an instance of the case class.

For instance, `Brand.tupled(("a","b"))` will give `Brand("a","b")`.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Is there a good way to simplify the case classes?